# Tips for designing an optical eight channel read head for a DIY rotary encoder

Tags: sensors, encoding

I'm thinking of using the [gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) optical encoder disc design described at [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326792/tikz-how-to-draw-an-optical-encoder-wheel/529936#529936) to sense the base rotation of a robot arm. Being able to vary the disc to suit the physical aspects of the particular situation is attractive.

[image: Encoder disc]

I've subsequently been thinking about putting together a matching 8 track reading head. Probably using something like [these](https://core-electronics.com.au/miniature-reflective-infrared-optical-sensors-5-pack-itr20001-t.html) miniature reflective IR optical sensors.

[image: IR sensors]

**Can anyone point me towards good resources for figuring out a read head design? Any tips for avoiding interference between tracks?**

At the moment I'm just thinking about mounting them as close together as I can on prototyping board and printing the tracks on the disc to be the same width as a single sensor.

Comment: you could stagger the sensors if they interfere with each other ... transmissive sensors may be more accurate than reflective sensors

Comment: Riffing on the transmissive idea, maybe work with an array rather than discrete parts. For starters, try a web search for "linear photosensor array". If the price and performance are right, it's not a problem to have are more pixels than you need.

Comment: @r-bryan great suggestion regarding array use. I found a low price reflective array at about the number of channels I’m looking for (link below). Did you have something similar in mind for a transmissive solution. https://www.pololu.com/product/4109

Comment: I was thinking something like the sensor used at https://arduining.com/2014/03/26/using-the-linear-sensor-array-tsl201r-with-arduino/ (except those are no longer available). Sort of like a 1-D camera, that's what I meant about more pixels than you have tracks. For that matter, it might not be cuckoo to think about like a RPi cam and a bit of image processing, depending on the rest of the requirements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the linear photo sensor array idea suggested by @r-bryan, and selected a [Pololu](https://www.pololu.com/product/4109) QTR-HD-09RC Reflectance Sensor Array: 9-Channel, 4mm Pitch, RC Output. I’ll update this answer with Tex code for printing a matching Gray code wheel when available.

I’ve initially chosen a digital output array. I’ve yet to read through the supplied Arduino [library](https://pololu.github.io/qtr-sensors-arduino/) to check for  a non-blocking solution. I may switch to the analog version if this becomes an issue after testing.

[image]